# How to add a full stop right behind a float() variable in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program for a computer programming course to calculate the area of a triangle, and the expected output is "The area is [insert number here]."

Here's what I have, and I'm frankly stumped on the full stop:

```
b = input('Base: ')
h = input('Height: ')
a = 0.5 * float(b) * float(h)
print('The area is', a, '.')
```

It outputs this:

```
Base: 1
Height: 1
The area is 0.5 .
```

This is marked as incorrect because of the extra space, how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Use proper formatting: `print(f'The area is {a}.')`

Comment: @KateMelnykova The attempt is already posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print default separator argument is `' '` (a space), so try changing that to `''` (empty string):

```
print('The area is ', a, '.', sep='')
```

Or use `+` and make it a string:

```
print('The area is ', str(a) + '.')
```

Best with string formatting:

`f` string literal:

```
print(f'The area is {a}.')
```

Or `%s`:

```
print('The area is %s.' % a)
```

Or `str.format`:

```
print('The area is {}.'.format(a))
```

Comment: No need for `f` in the last example.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek Ah yah! Typo, thanks!

Comment: @Selcuk Yeah true, edited my answer